# Mapping inside of mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a fake payload data for my app and I'm testing going through the payload with map() function. However while I can return correct number of divs after mapping with some of the data correct I cant find proper configuration for returning a payload ID. What am I doing wrong?

Database looks like this:

```
export default [
{
    payloadId: 0,
    drugsId:[0, 29],
    lat: 51.760549449821696,
    lon: 19.403501300000016
},
{
    payloadId: 1,
    drugsId:[3],
    lat: 52.760549449821696,
    lon: 17.403501300000016
},
{
    payloadId: 2,
    drugsId:[5, 19, 14, 31],
    lat: 53.760549449821696,
    lon: 29.403501300000016
},
{
    payloadId: 3,
    drugsId:[3, 9],
    lat: 53.760549449821696,
    lon: 16.403501300000016
}
]
```

My react component where I render the random payload looks like this (all correct data is passed from the parent):

```
import React from 'react';

class WherepothecaryPanel extends React.Component{
render(){

    const fakePayload = this.props.fakePayload;

    const rngPayloadId = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);


    console.log('Random payload id', rngPayloadId)


    const payload = fakePayload.map(payload =>{
        if(payload.payloadId === rngPayloadId){
           return payload.drugsId.map(drug => {
               return <div> Drug ID: {drug.drugsId}, lat: {payload.lat}, lon: {payload.lon} </div>
           })
        }
    })

    return(
        <div>
            <div id='wherepothecaryPanel' className='col-xs-8'>
                {payload}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default WherepothecaryPanel
```

In this configuration my return looks like this for example:

```
Drug ID: , lat: 51.760549449821696, lon: 19.403501300000016
Drug ID: , lat: 51.760549449821696, lon: 19.403501300000016
```

Comment: `payload.drugsId` is an array of integers; calling `map()` on it means `drug` inside your mapping function is an integer (not a drug object). I'm also not clear what exactly you expect the return to be; if you want the `id`, just replace `drug.drugsId` with `drug`

Comment: You are correct. thats what picked answer also proposed, I was trying to complicate things when it wasnt complicated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
 const payload = fakePayload.map(payload =>{
    if(payload.payloadId === rngPayloadId){
       // you are mapping through ids, so just have to use as value {id}
       return payload.drugsId.map(id => {
           return <div> Drug ID: {id}, lat: {payload.lat}, lon: {payload.lon} </div>
       })
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried to overcomplicate this, sigh, your solution is perfect and now I feel dumb, thank you!